# Tkinter - How to delete images with a button?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I plan to create "the game of matches" in python with the Tkinter module as a graphical interface, you should know that I started learning to use Tkinter only since yesterday, my code is certainly very ugly...

So I first created a home menu and then a player versus player mode, and so as you can see in this image:
[image: 1]
**As you can see the goal here to offer the user to take one, two or three matches and I would like the corresponding match images to be deleted!**
Until there's none left

Here is the corresponding part in my code:

```
nb_allumettes = 21
allum_list=[]


# Definition of a function that creates the buttons to take matches:
def crea_button(racine,canvas):
    v=canvas.create_text(540, 525, text="Combien d'allumette(s) prenez-vous ?",font=("Helvetica", 30), fill="white")
    w=canvas.create_rectangle(canvas.bbox(v),fill="#00bdfb")
    canvas.tag_lower(w,v)
    button1 = Button(racine, text="1 allumette", command=lambda *args: suppr_allum(1), font=("Helvetica", 14), fg='white', bg="#00bdfb", height = 2, width = 18)
    button1_window = canvas.create_window(75, 560, anchor='nw', window=button1)
    button2 = Button(racine, text="2 allumettes", command=lambda *args: suppr_allum(2), font=("Helvetica", 14), fg='white', bg="#00bdfb", height = 2, width = 18)
    button2_window = canvas.create_window(430, 560, anchor='nw', window=button2)
    button3 = Button(racine, text="3 allumettes", command=lambda *args: suppr_allum(3), font=("Helvetica", 14), fg='white', bg="#00bdfb", height = 2, width = 18)
    button3_window = canvas.create_window(780, 560, anchor='nw', window=button3)
    return button1_window, button2_window, button3_window

def spawn_allumettes(canvas):
    global allum_list
    allum_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "allum_v1.png")
    allum1 = canvas.create_image(-30, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum2 = canvas.create_image(20, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum3 = canvas.create_image(70, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum4 = canvas.create_image(120, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum5 = canvas.create_image(170, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum6 = canvas.create_image(220, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum7 = canvas.create_image(270, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum8 = canvas.create_image(320, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum9 = canvas.create_image(370, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum10 = canvas.create_image(420, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum11 = canvas.create_image(470, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum12 = canvas.create_image(520, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum13 = canvas.create_image(570, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum14 = canvas.create_image(620, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum15 = canvas.create_image(670, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum16 = canvas.create_image(720, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum17 = canvas.create_image(770, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum18 = canvas.create_image(820, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum19 = canvas.create_image(870, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum20 = canvas.create_image(920, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum21 = canvas.create_image(970, 100, image = allum_img, anchor = 'nw')
    allum_list = [allum1, allum2, allum3, allum4, allum5, allum6, allum7, allum8, allum9, allum10, allum11, allum12, allum13, allum14,
    allum15, allum16, allum17, allum18, allum19, allum20, allum21]
    mainloop()


def suppr_allum(number):
    global nb_allumettes
    nb_allumettes = nb_allumettes - number
    print(number)
    print(nb_allumettes)
    print(allum_list)
    if number == 3:
        allum_list[0].delete()
        allum_list[1].delete()
        allum_list[2].delete()
    elif number == 2:
        allum_list[0].delete()
        allum_list[1].delete()
    elif number == 1:
        allum_list[0].delete()


# Define a function that opens the Player 1 versus Player 2 mode window:
def open_mode_jcj():
    root_jcj = Toplevel(root)
    root_jcj.title("Partie entre deux joueurs")
    root_jcj.geometry("1080x720")
    root_jcj.minsize(1080, 720)
    root_jcj.maxsize(1080, 720)
    # Importer et afficher une image de fond :
    canvas_jcj = Canvas(root_jcj, width = 1080, height = 720)
    canvas_jcj.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
    bg3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "Background_IMAGE.png")
    canvas_jcj.create_image( 0, 0, image = bg3, anchor = "nw")
    crea_button(root_jcj,canvas_jcj)
    list_allum = []
    list_allum = spawn_allumettes(canvas_jcj)
    if nb_allumettes == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Perdu")

root.mainloop()
```

I have already seen that there are different commands to delete elements:

```
.delete()
.destroy()
.pack_forget()
```

I also tried packing each image but that makes all the matches disappear so that only one remains...

Thanks in advance for those who will help me!

Comment: You can delete objects on a `Canvas`  by using its [`delete()`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/canvas-methods.html) method. You don't need to `pack()` objects created on canvases.

Comment: If you want to delete all the object with a certain rectangular region, you can use the `.find_enclosed()` method `Canvas`es also have to obtain their ids.

Comment: Thaks @martineau for your answer, so I tried this command and here I tried only on the first match on the far left: 
`kxa = -30 
kya = 100 
kxb = 134 
kyb = 400 
if number == 3: 
         allum_detect_1 = canvas_allum.find_enclosed(kxa, kya, kxb, kyb) 
         allum_detect_1.delete()`
But this command create a tuple and I have this error in the output :
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'delete'`
I also tried with the .destroy() function and I have exactly the same problem...

Comment: Oh @martineau it's good I found how to do it! In fact I read the documentation you linked and I understood that the correct command is: `canvas_allum.delete(allum_detect_1)` It works perfectly! Thank you !

Comment: That's good to hear. Indeed, `find_closed()` always returns a sequence of object ids as a tuple whose length will vary depending on how many object it found within the region specified. Note that the length can be more than one or even zero.